# Error al iniciar un proyecto de Vue

Tags: nodejs, vue.js

Estoy intentando iniciar un nuevo proyecto de vue `vue create <nombre del proyecto>`,
todo el proceso de configuracion del proyecto funciona correctamente, a la hora de seleccionar vuex, router, babel, etc, todo correct. Una vez el proyecto se configura se inicia la instalación y al cabo de unos segundos, me dice este error que os dejo en la imagen.

Probé a eliminar vue de forma global, a eliminar node y todas sus configuraciones y reinstalarlo todo de cero, pero el problema persiste.

Os adjunto 2 capturas de pantalla, muchas gracias a todos.

[image: Imagen del errro]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: te sigue pasando? Ayer fue un día complejo para github y repercutió en npmjs

Comment: Buenas tardes, se solucionó reinstalando una version anterior de npm. npm i -g npm@6.14.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me paso hace unos meses con un proyecto de vuecli vuetify, **esto se debe que el paquete no es compatible con la versión cli 3 del proyecto**

Muchas empresas han querido aplicar la actualización pero esta versión scaffold crea conflictos con otros paquetes, trata de cargarte todo por el [vue ui](https://cli.vuejs.org/dev-guide/ui-api.html) y pon la consola o terminal a un lado para observar el proceso.

solo instala el vue 3 luego vas por router y vuex, la versión que me dio dolores de cabeza fue la versión 4.5.x (actual 2020)